# How can I create this UI in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I want this UI in flutter.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NrhBq.png)

Comment: try a GridView with fixedCrossAxisCount set to  3

Answer (score 1):

Here is code where I did something similar. It has a `GridView` which shows `GridTile`s, which have a `FadeInImage` and a `GridTileBar`.

```
class ProductsGrid extends StatelessWidget {
  final favouritesOnly;

  ProductsGrid(this.favouritesOnly);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var productsProvider = Provider.of<Products>(context);
    var products =
        favouritesOnly ? productsProvider.favourites : productsProvider.items;

    return GridView.builder(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
      itemCount: products.length,
      gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
        crossAxisCount: 2,
        childAspectRatio: 3 / 2,
        crossAxisSpacing: 10,
        mainAxisSpacing: 10,
      ),
      itemBuilder: (context, index) => ChangeNotifierProvider.value(
        value: products[index],
        child: ProductItem(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ProductItem extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final product = Provider.of<Product>(context, listen: false);
    final cart = Provider.of<Cart>(context, listen: false);
    final auth = Provider.of<Auth>(context, listen: false);
    final scaffold = Scaffold.of(context);

    return ClipRRect(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
        child: GridTile(
          child: GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {
              Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(
                ProductDetailScreen.routeName,
                arguments: product.id,
              );
            },
            child: FadeInImage(
              placeholder: AssetImage('assets/images/product_placeholder.png'),
              image: NetworkImage(product.imageUrl),
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
            ),
          ),
          footer: GridTileBar(
            leading: Consumer<Product>(
              builder: (context, product, child) => IconButton(
                icon: Icon(product.isFavourite
                    ? Icons.favorite
                    : Icons.favorite_border),
                color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
                onPressed: () async {
                  try {
                    await product.toggleFavourite(auth.token, auth.userId);
                  } catch (error) {
                    print(error);
                    scaffold.showSnackBar(SnackBar(
                      content: Text(
                        error.toString(),
                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                      ),
                    ));
                  }
                },
              ),
              // child: optional invariant child widget to provide to builder
            ),
            title: Text(
              product.title,
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            ),
            trailing: IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.shopping_cart),
              color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
              onPressed: () {
                cart.addItem(product.id, product.title, product.price);
                Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
                    content: Text('Added item to cart'),
                    duration: Duration(seconds: 2),
                    action: SnackBarAction(
                        label: 'UNDO',
                        onPressed: () {
                          cart.removeSingleItem(product.id);
                        })));
              },
            ),
            backgroundColor: Colors.black87,
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```